# Como decodificar valores vindos de javascript?

Tags: php, angularjs, json

boa noite a todos!!
Pessoal, seguinte, estou recebendo a seguinte variável de uma aplicação em angulajs:

```
   Array ( [{"nome":"volks","descricao":"conheça_o_novo_modelo_da_volks"}] => )
```

como eu consigo converter ele de modo que consiga acessar seus valores?
obrigado a todos!!
Horácio

Editado:
Esse é o codigo que recebe os dados:

```
<?php
$dados = $_REQUEST;
print_r($dados);
/*
header('Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8');
$x = array("info_recebida"=> $_REQUEST);
echo json_encode($x);
```

aqui momentaneamente só estou exibindo, e foi de onde eu trouxe a variável acima

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo o [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php), você pode utilizar a função **json_decode**

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

**Solução:**

```
$dados = $_REQUEST;
// ou $dados = $_POST;
print_r(json_decode(dados));
```

Comment: então eu fiz desse jeito, porém, recebendo os dados acima, e o resultado foi esse:
<br /> <b>Warning</b>: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_da_corretora\site\wp-content\themes\slice_tema\page-update_carro.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br /> NULL <br /> <b>Warning</b>: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_da_corretora\site\wp-content\themes\slice_tema\page-update_carro.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br /> NULL

Comment: Edita a pergunta e coloca o código `php`

Comment: editei, eu coloquei o código que vc tinha enviado, mas aí, tirei e deixei apenas a exibição...
na exibição, ele traz o
    Array ( 
   [{"nome":"volks","descricao":"conheça_o_novo_modelo_da_volks"}] => )

Comment: Editei a resposta, tenta do jeito que deixei

Comment: então...
eu copiei e colei assim:
<?php
$dados = $_POST;
// ou $dados = $_POST;
print_r(json_decode($dados));

o retorno foi :
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog_da_corretora\site\wp-content\themes\slice_tema\page-update_carro.php on line 4

Comment: Veja um [tutorial angular e php](http://shabeebk.com/blog/simple-form-submit-in-angularjs-with-php/)

Comment: entendi...é caminho que eu iria se fosse com put...achei que desse para fazer do outro jeito no caso do post!! 
Muito obrigado pela luz, Wellington!!
Grande abraço!!!
Boa noite!!